# ORACLE, how i use two diferent filtres in same table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this problem: in the same table i need to get the ID´s with have only two CODES at the same time, EX:

TABLE1

```
ID | CODE
1  | A
1  | B
2  | C
2  | B
3  | C
3  | A
4  | A
5  | C
```

Example: i need to get only the ID´s with the CODE 'A' and 'B' at same time, in the TABLE1 the answer is only the ID 1

so i count whats ID have two CODE´s:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(CODE) = 2
```

And i filter whats CODE´s are 'A' OR 'B'

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE1
WHERE (CODE = 'A' OR 'B')
```

But how i combine this two queries?

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation on the answer given by @Lukasz:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE1
WHERE Code IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Code) = 2;
```

Comment: Cleanest, most obvious and concise!

Comment: Work perfectly, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little ambiguous.  If you want A/B together -- and other codes are allowed as well -- then:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CODE IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MIN(CODE) = 'A' and MAX(CODE) = 'B';
```

You can also use:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CODE) = 2;
```

However, `COUNT(DISTINCT)` typically has worse performance.

Comment: I have seen you mention this about the performance of count distinct before.  Could you add a comment about this?  I guess an index could be used with min and max perhaps, but not with count?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Basically, to implement `DISTINCT` (either with `SELECT` or an aggregation function), the underlying database has to keep of list of values that have already been seen.  This is much more complicated than a `SUM()`, `MIN()`, or `MAX()`, where only one value is kept at each point.  There *are* some cases where an index can be used for the `DISTINCT`, but in general, it is going to be slower.

Comment: You've got my upvote +1.  I guess we might have to use count though, if the OP wanted to assert _more_ than two items.

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY ID 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Code IN('A','B') THEN Code END) = 2;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9247df3964078365dbad6d947da82638)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.code = 'C');
```